# C++ object creation or function prototype declaration

Tags: c++, gcc

A strange C++ compiler behavior caught me by surprise today.

```
class Foo {
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Foo& rhs)
    {
       return os << sizeof(rhs) <<  endl;
    }
};

struct Bar { };

int main()
{
    Foo f(Bar());
    cout << f;
    return 0;
}
```

Apparantly, the code above compiled fine, even though there was no

```
Foo(const Bar&);
```

c'tor defined. Compiling with -Wall showed that the compiler interprets the expression

```
Foo f(Bar());
```

as a prototype for a function

```
Foo f(Bar (*)())
```

instead of an expression for creating an object of type Foo.

What really is the catch (rule) here??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Most vexing parse: why doesn't A a(()); work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work)

Comment: Thanks Oswald for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Foo f(Bar());
```

Here compiler is assuming is to be a function call as a result of C++ "most vexing parse".

What you can do is just put one more parenthesis around your object.

```
Foo f((Bar()));
```

If you see C++11 documentation there are more ways to avoid this behavior.